# solution of mqttlens auto zoom in windows 8.1

Tags: mqtt, phpmqtt, ruby-mqtt, spring-integration-mqtt

I have installed `mqttlens` from `google chorme apps`.

It worked quite well for a couple of week, but recently it appears in zoom when I start it.

How can I fix it?

[image: click here to see the screenshort of my problem].

Comment: what happens if you press ctrl-0

Comment: No change if i press ctrl-0 @hardillb

Comment: Same issue, using v0.0.13, anyone manage to solve this?